# Crawl web application (ASP.net) with a login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, python-3.x, python-requests, web-crawler

I want to crawl a web application (ASP.NET) which requires a login.

URL I want to crawl data from: https://wo.gruposese.com/mod_Clientes/Pedido

URL of the login: https://wo.gruposese.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx

I tried the following code (I am using a proxy, but in this code Im leaving out the proxy part because it works fine, which means I can get the plain HTML code from the website but just cant log in - so it should not be the problem):

```
import requests
from lxml import html

username = "I-am-a-username"
password = "I-am-a-password"
url = "https://wo.gruposese.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx"

session_requests = requests.session()
result = session_requests.get(url)

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
auth_key = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='__VIEWSTATE']/@value")))[0]

payload = {
    "LoginControl$UserName": username,
    "LoginControl$Password": password,
    "__VIEWSTATE": auth_key
}

session_requests.get(url, data=payload, headers=dict(referer=url))
```

However, I receive a seemingly endless error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    158             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 159                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    160 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     56 
---> 57     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     58         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

C:\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    747     addrlist = []
--> 748     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    749         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    342         try:
--> 343             self._validate_conn(conn)
    344         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    838         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 839             conn.connect()
    840 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    300         # Add certificate verification
--> 301         conn = self._new_conn()
    302         hostname = self.host

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    167             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 168                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    169 

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000006B0B48470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    397         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 398             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    399 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='wo.gruposese.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000006B0B48470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f6691b6c307b> in <module>
     23 
     24 
---> 25 session_requests.get(url, data=payload, headers=dict(referer=url))

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in get(self, url, **kwargs)
    544 
    545         kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
--> 546         return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    547 
    548     def options(self, url, **kwargs):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='wo.gruposese.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000006B0B48470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

I have two questions:

1. I apparantly got something wrong here but I already tried so much and nothing works for me. I normally assume to have a csrf token to use in the payload dictionary - but this website seem to not have one... I am not sure if "__VIEWSTATE" is the problem here.
2. Also, I wonder how I can proceed after a login to the actual webpage (see URL above) in this ASP.net case and crawl data from there?

P.S. Im not allowed to install Selenium and hence need to solve the problem with requests or scrapy.

Comment: For #1, ASP.Net Viewstate can be complicated. Sometimes it depends on javascript, and if you don't replicate that precisely the pages won't render the right data. For example, rather than a get request to a url for the next page, you might instead need to post a generic "next" button click to the same page to increment a ViewState or Session value you can't read cleanly. For this reason, ASP.net webforms pages have a reputation of being a little harder to crawl. Often, site owners see this as a feature.

Comment: For part #2, the server will likely set a cookie you must include along with subsequent requests. That cookie will contain an auth token that will be validated against your request signature (same source IP/user agent/csrf token).